# let : $y=(2x-1)^2 \sqrt{x^2+4x}$ then fine the :

Tags: calculus, derivatives

let : $y=(2x-1)^2 \sqrt{x^2+4x}$ then fine the :

$$f''(\frac{1}{2})=?$$

---

My try :

$$f'(\frac{1}{2})=\lim _{x\to\frac{1}{2}}\frac{2((2x-1)^2 \sqrt{x^2+4x})-0}{2x-1}=0$$

Now $f''(\frac{1}{2})$ how ?

Answer (score 1):

the first derivative is given by
$$f'(x)=4\, \left( 2\,x-1 \right) \sqrt {{x}^{2}+4\,x}+1/2\,{\frac { \left( 2
\,x-1 \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,x+4 \right) }{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+4\,x}}}
$$ and $$f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$
for the second derivative we get
$$f''(x)=8\,\sqrt {{x}^{2}+4\,x}+4\,{\frac { \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 2\,x
+4 \right) }{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+4\,x}}}-1/4\,{\frac { \left( 2\,x-1
 \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,x+4 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+4\,x
 \right) ^{3/2}}}+{\frac { \left( 2\,x-1 \right) ^{2}}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+
4\,x}}}
$$ and $$f''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=12$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(2x-1)^2=u$ and $\sqrt{x^2+4x}=v.$

Thus, $$f''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=(u'v+uv')'_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=(u''v+2u'v'+uv'')_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$=u''v_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=8\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+4\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=12.$$